# Amavis won't start on systemctl

Tags: ubuntu, amavis, ubuntu-18.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 that I have installed ISPConfig 3 on. I've done this same install multiple times with no problems. For some reason this time Amavis won't start at all using init scripts.

If I run `systemctl restart amavis` it gives me this:

```
amavis.service - LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/amavis; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-09-20 08:52:55 EDT; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3587 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/amavis stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3596 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amavis start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 20 08:52:55 mx2.proverbs.microtronix-tech.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter...
Sep 20 08:52:55 mx2.proverbs.microtronix-tech.com amavis[3596]: Starting amavisd:
Sep 20 08:52:55 mx2.proverbs.microtronix-tech.com amavis[3596]: Warning: Fake start-stop-daemon called, doing nothing.
Sep 20 08:52:55 mx2.proverbs.microtronix-tech.com amavis[3596]: amavisd-new.
Sep 20 08:52:55 mx2.proverbs.microtronix-tech.com systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter.
```

Then running `netstat -tap | grep amavis` returns nothing. Checking syslog there are no conceivable errors other than the `Fake start-stop-daemon` error.

However, if I run `amavisd-new debug` it starts fine, and netstat does return results:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3986/amavisd-new (m 
tcp        0      0 localhost:10026         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3986/amavisd-new (m 
tcp6       0      0 localhost:10024         [::]:*                  LISTEN      3986/amavisd-new (m 
tcp6       0      0 localhost:10026         [::]:*                  LISTEN      3986/amavisd-new (m
```

So I don't think it's the config since it start fine there and mail delivery then works on this server. But through init scripts it doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this message comes from a broken install / upgrade of the OS / a package.

Your best bet is to run some commands and see if they fix the situation:

```
apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f amavisd-new
```

If that's not enough, **backup your system first** (these commands can break the OS), then proceed checking for configuration issues with dpkg and brute force reinstall amavis-new

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq amavisd-new
```

and then

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```